# How can I get If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match headers in IIS when using some sort of wildcard mapping?

Tags: iis

I have an image server, that takes URLs of the form

```
http://www.myserver.com/photo/foo/bar/baz/~120x120/crop/abc123.jpg
```

and dynamically generates thumbnails based on the parameters parsed from the URL string. We've had this running in two configurations - one by mapping the 404 error in IIS to a .aspx page, with the image processing in the code-behind, and a second by implementing `IHttpHandler` and adding a line to the `system.web` section of `/photo/web.config` like so:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="*" type="App_Code.ThumbnailHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

I need to add some support for HTTP caching, but in both configurations, **IIS is silently stripping the `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` headers** - Fiddler shows the browser sending them to the server, but then they're gone by the time my page or handler gets access to the `Request.Headers` collection.

How can I write a piece of code that handles arbitrary, wildcard URL requests, with ANY file extension, but can still access the headers I need to be able to respond with a `304 Not Modified` if the client already has a current version of the resource? My next thing to try would be rewriting it as an MVC application but that really seems like overkill.

EDIT: OK, what's REALLY crazy is that if I hit

```
http://www.myserver.com/photo/this/is/a/random/string/of/gibberish.aspx
```

(i.e. with .ASPX file extension) - the headers are INTACT! But if I hit

```
http://www.myserver.com/photo/this/is/a/random/string/of/gibberish.jpg
```

They're missing... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I've found for this is to implement IHttpHandler as described above, but then map every file extension you're 'matching' (in our case .JPG, .PNG and .TIF) to %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll in IIS. That, for some bizarre reason, means IIS will invoke your HTTP handler without mangling the headers first.